# AngularJS merge Arrays for ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, arrays, json

I have my posts saved in a .json file. My likes for each post are saved in another php file which is connected to my database.

```
 a.likesA = [];

 $http({
     method: 'GET',
     url: 'data/get_likes.php'
 }).then(function(response) {
     a.likesA = response.data;
     console.log(response.data);
 }, function(error) {
     console.log("Likes konnten nicht geladen werden: " + error.status + error.statusText);
 });


 a.labs = []; //declare an empty array

 $http({
     method: 'GET',
     url: 'data/lab.json'
 }).then(function(response) {
     a.labs = response.data;
     //console.log(response.data.length);
 }, function(error) {
     console.log("JSON konnte nicht geladen werden: " + error.status + error.statusText);
 });
```

I want to display each post with the corresponding like-number.

i tried this: `ng-repeat="lab in combined = labs.concat(likesA)` but then i got 6 ng-repeats instead of 3. (i currently have 3 posts in my .json)

Comment: Will you create fiddle so we can help you better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why cant you do like this. Where you use the `$index` property of labs to get the respective number of likes.

```js
// <body ng-app='myApp' binds to the app being created below.
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

// Register MyController object to this app
app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', MyController]);    

// We define a simple controller constructor.
function MyController($scope) {
    $scope.likes=[5,4,3,2,1];
    $scope.labs = ['5', '4', '3', '2', '1'];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller='MyController' ng-app='myApp'>
    <div ng-repeat="lab in labs">
      <div>Lab Index: {{lab}}</div>
      <div>Number of likes:{{likes[$index]}}</div>
      <br>
      <br>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, `Object.assign` will merge array or objects

```
var combined = Object.assign([], labs, likesA);

ng-repeat="lab in combined"
```